# Taylor Series, Taylor Theorem

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider a continuous and differentiable function $G$ of two variables $x$ and $y$. If $\delta x$, $\delta y$ are small changes in $x$ and $y$, respectively, and $\delta G$ is the resulting small change in $G$, then by using the Taylor Series, we have
\begin{equation}
\delta G = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}\delta y + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}\delta x^2 + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial y}\delta x\delta y + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial y^2}\delta y^2 + \cdots
\end{equation}
As the limits $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ tend to zero, why the previous equation becomes
\begin{equation}
dG=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy,
\end{equation}
rather than
\begin{equation}
dG=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}dx^2 + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial y}dxdy + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{dy^2}\delta y^2 + \cdots
\end{equation}?

Thanks.

Comment: Think of computing the geometrically meaningful $$\frac{dG}{dt}$$ where $x$ and $y$ each depend on $t$.  Perhaps better understandable than the geometrically questionable $dG$ by itself.

Comment: Because we are assuming that $dx, dy$ are small.  It which case $dx^2, dy^2,dxdy $ are very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the differential $dG$ is a *linear* approximation to the change in $G$ near a point. Informally, this lets us ignore higher-order terms in the actual difference. More formally, $dG_{\mathbf x}$, when it exists, is the linear map such that $\delta G_{\mathbf x}[\mathbf h]=dG_{\mathbf x}[\mathbf h]+o(\|\mathbf h\|)$. Comparing this to the Taylor Series, we have $$dG(\delta x,\delta y)={\partial G\over\partial x}\delta x+{\partial G\over\partial y}\delta y,$$ while the second-degree and higher terms in $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ are subsumed into $o(\|(\delta x,\delta y)\|)$.

Comment: Thanks, but why not\begin{equation}
dG\approx\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy~~~~~~~~~?\end{equation}

Comment: @StephenGe But what do $dx$ and $dy$ mean in that expression? I’m emphasizing that $dG_{\mathbf x}$ is simply a linear map that takes a vector $(\delta x,\delta y)$ that represents a displacement from $\mathbf x$ and spits out a number. Now, if you view $x$ and $y$ as affine coordinate functions of the point $\mathbf x$, then the differential $dx$ is equal to $\delta x$ (sim. for $y$) and the chain rule indeed yields $dG=G_x\,dx+G_y\,dy$.